Improper Token Passed while logging in discord with discord.py
I am creating a python code that reads the messages I receive in my MD and displays them on the screen. But I get the error Improper token has been passed. I saw another posts with the same problem but didn´t solve.
I´m not creating a bot, I´m creating a message reader.
I tried putting my user´s token. This should work but I receive that message.
The code is:
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True 

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            # Verify DM messages
            print(f'DM message received: {message.content}')

TOKEN = '***'

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run(TOKEN)


The error is what it says. Improper token passed while logging in discord. Go to your discord appliction page. Select the one you are using and reset the token. Copy the token and use it.

@Brawldude2 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not creating an application or a bot, I'm simply reading the messages with the code, which I assume would use my user token to log in.

It doesn't work like that. You can't use a non-app token discord doesn't allow that for security reasons. You should always use your application token even if you are simply going to establish a connection with discord. Anything that requires you to interact with discord API requires you to use bot token.

The Client class of discord.py is not for User-Bots (these are banned in the Discord TOS), but an instance which just defines the most simple thing you need to connect to an application account on discord. the token does not accept a user token, because this library is only made for discord applications.
